# Unable to get functionapp create to work with Python on Azure

Tags: python, azure-functions

Trying to deploy an Azure function using the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash%2Cbrowser#create-supporting-azure-resources-for-your-function and I am unable to get functionapp create to create a Python function app. I'm using Python 3.7.8, the function's name is challenge, and I plan to deploy to Azure, where I already have a site running that's mostly C#. I'm invoking it like this in the command shell:

`az functionapp create --consumption-plan-location westus --runtime python --runtime-version 3.7 --functions-version 3 --name challenge --os-type windows`

And I get this error:

`usage error: Currently supported runtimes (--runtime) in windows function apps are: dotnet-isolated, dotnet, node, custom, java, powershell.`

According to the [az function app create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_functionapp_create) docs `python` should work.

I did try this in desperation:

`az functionapp create --consumption-plan-location westus --runtime dotnet --functions-version 3 --name challenge --os-type windows`

This yielded the error message `Operation returned an invalid status 'Conflict'`.

How can I deploy a Python function app on Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Python for Azure functions is only supported using a linux based runtimes ([see note on Python Functions developer reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=azurecli-linux%2Capplication-level), [and available system/runtime combinations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#operating-systemruntime).

You'll either want to look at using a linux-code only function or deploying your code as a linux docker container.

Comment: linux didn't work! I tried things like `az functionapp create --consumption-plan-location westeurope --runtime python --runtime-version 3.7  --functions-version 3 --name challenge --os-type linux` and still got the error message `Operation returned an invalid status 'Conflict'`

Comment: Try adding the `--debug` option to get a more verbose output?